# Saving dictionary key values to a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I am passing keyword as the parameter to function and want to save the value of that keyword to a variable.

The is in the form of a dictionary:
[image: output]

This is the code so far:

```
def foo(**var2):
    print (var2)

foo(source_id=3, limit = 200)
foo(research_id = 1)
```

I want to save values of `source_id`, `limit` and `research_id` to a variable.

Comment: Try `source_id = var2.get('source_id)`

Comment: This is working source_id = var2.get('source_id') but this is not 
source_ids = var2.get('source_id')...Why is that?

Comment: I didn't get the point, is `source_ids` is a list? Did you mean `foo(source_ids=[1, 2, 3])` ?

Comment: I mean, while we are saving the variable for source_id, the keyword and the variable name is same.Can we change the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the keyword arguments into variables, you should try:

```
def foo(**var2):
    s_id = var2.get('source_id')
    limit = var2.get('limit')
    research_id = var2.get('research_id')
    print('source_id = ', s_id)
    print('limit = ', limit)
    print('research_id = ', research_id)

foo(source_id=3, limit=200)
```

prints

```
source_id =  3
limit =  200
research_id = None
```

and

```
foo(research_id=1)
```

prints

```
source_id =  None
limit =  None
research_id = 1
```

Comment: can I give different variable names like s_id in place of source_id?

Comment: @Hayat: Definitely, you can name the inner variables as you like. But the name of dict key should match the keyword argument :)

Comment: @Hayat: See my edited answer, I have changed the variable name to `s_id`, is that you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
def foo(**var2):
    for val in var2.values():
        print(val)
        # you can save the values to other variables here
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after:

```
def foo(**var2):
    print (var2)
    vars_passed = list(var2.values())
    return vars_passed

res = foo(source_id=3, limit = 200)
print(res)  # -> [3, 200]
```

---

**NOTE**

I would not recommend the above practice because ordering in `dictionaries` is not guaranteed. As a result, in your case, you can't be sure what `3` and what `200` is. I would get the whole `dict`.

Comment: So what if I try to access values based on keys.That will always give me proper value.But I don't know to do that with the different variable name.